# popover change position starting point (origin location) iOS9

Tags: ios, swift

I want to present my popover at a different location.  By default it begins where the user selects the button.  I am using UIVIewController instead of UIPopoverController because UIPopoverController is deprecated in iOS9

```
class CustomPop: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

init() {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover;
    self.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self;
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle{
    return .None
}
}

//for example something like this but I need it for a popover:
custom = CustomPop()
custom.frame.origin.y = self.view.height - 100
// is there a way to use CGRectMake for the popover to accomplish this?
```

Comment: you want the popover to be in an exact location or perhaps you want the arrow to be on the left size of the popover or the middle or the left or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

```
custom.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)
```

CGRectMake(x.origin, y.origin, width, height)

Comment: You also need to set the popover controller's `sourceView`.

Comment: yeah I set the sourceView =  sender as? UIView

Answer (score 0):

**New solution iOS 8+**

```
// Create Controller

var popoverContent = CustomPop()

// Get NavController
var nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popoverContent)
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover

// Get PopoverPresentationController 
var popover = nav.popoverPresentationController as UIPopoverPresentationController
popover.sourceView = self.view
popover.sourceRect = CGRectMake(100,100,0,0)

// Show Popover
self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

*Use a UIPopoverController **Deprecated***

```
// Create Controller
UIPopoverController *pc = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];

// Set Point
[pc presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
                    inView:self.view 
                    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                    animated:YES];
```

Comment: I dont have the option to use presentpopoverfromrect

Comment: Why not? You cannot use an UIPopoverController?

Comment: I added more code to the question to show how I'm creating the popover

Comment: Ok, but i think you can use an UIPopoverController. Just create your customViewController (CustomPop) and pass it to initWithContentViewController.

Comment: UIPopoverController was deprecated in iOS9 so I want to avoid using it.  They want us to use UIVIewController instead and that't why im using CustomPop which is a UIViewController

Comment: Oh i am sorry! But than you can easily change the position of the frame or not?

Comment: I've tried changing the frame using custom.view.frame.origin.y but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you use an NavigationController?

Comment: Hope the new solution can help you

Comment: the solution works however, it covers my previous viewcontroller completely

Comment: Try to set the content size. popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(100,100)

Comment: I really do appreciate all the help. But it looks like its replacing the currentviewcontroller with the new one.  it doesn't act like a popover (it hides the previous view controller, and when clicking outside of the content it doesnt dismiss the new viewcontroller)

Comment: figured it out with the original code, thank you for all the help custom.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)

Answer (score -2):

try this in **swift 3.1** :

```
MZFormSheetPresentationController.appearance().movementActionWhenKeyboardAppears = .alwaysAboveKeyboard
```